# set variable and call result during FOR loop; batch script windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I have read several posts here on Stackoverflow about binding a variable during a FOR loop. While I figure most of the help provided here has been for Linux/Unix, I'm reaching out for help with batch scripting in Windows. My main goal is to extract the "date created" from a mp4-file and "overlay the date on my video" using ffmpeg (and or ffprobe).

I have experimented a lot, but my latest attempt has been trying to bind the result from ffprobe onto a variable, and use the variable later. My latest and simplest attempt looks like this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do (
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('ffprobe -v quiet %%a -print_format compact -show_entries format_tags=creation_time') do (
set DateC=%%G
echo !DateC!)
)
```

I was hoping to be able to print the tag result from ffprobe using that code, but apparently not. So helping me bind that variable, and how to call it again later inside the following code snippet in Windows, would be deeply appreciated:

```
 ffmpeg -i %%a -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:x=28:y=650:fontsize=45:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.4:text='!DateC!'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

I must also mention I've seen the following code on StackOverflow:

```
 ffmpeg -i %%a -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:x=28:y=650:fontsize=45:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.4:text='%{metadata\:creation_time}'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

But I have the same problem making Windows recognize and print the metadata.

I am certain the file in question contains this metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this not tested code for the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%G in ('ffprobe.exe -v quiet "%%a" -print_format compact -show_entries format_tags^=creation_time 2^>^&1') do (
        set "DateC=%%G"
        echo !DateC!
    )
)
endlocal
```

The inner **FOR** runs in a separate command process started with `cmd /C` the command line:

```
ffprobe.exe -v quiet "%%a" -print_format compact -show_entries format_tags=creation_time 2>&1
```

`"%%a"` is already replaced by name of current *.mp4 file. The double quotes are necessary in case of current *.mp4 file name contains a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

It is necessary to escape the equal sign with `^` in arguments list to get the command line correct passed to `cmd.exe` started by **FOR** in background.

`2>&1` results in redirecting output written to handle **STDERR** to handle **STDOUT** because of **FOR** captures only everything written to **STDOUT** of the started command process.

The redirection operators `>` and `&` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `ffprobe.exe` command line in the separate command process started in background.

I don't have `ffprobe.exe` and `ffmpeg.exe` installed, but I think those console applications write information about files to handle **STDERR** (standard error) instead of **STDOUT** (standard output) which is the reason for using `2>&1` to get the wanted information captured by **FOR** and assigned to an environment variable.

`"tokens=*"` is the same as `"delims="`. Both result in getting the entire line captured by **FOR** assigned to loop variable `G` without splitting it up into substrings (tokens) using space/tab as delimiters, except the line starts with a semicolon in which case **FOR** would ignore that line completely for processing because of internal default `eol=;`.